# iOS: Rotating a line with respect to a point that could be adjusted by touch

Tags: ios, core-graphics, quartz-2d, cgaffinetransform, uibezierpath

[image: Line rotation around specific point]

Man, have I been struggling with this...

In reference to the image above, I have a line that is fixed to a specific point. At the other end of the line I have another point that is NOT fixed and could be dragged to any position on the screen. I need the line to be able to follow that point and be rotated with respect to it's position WITHOUT changing lengths.

I know all of this could be accomplished quite easily without having the line be a fixed length.

You could simply draw a `UIBezierPath` in `drawRect:` like this:

```
UIBezierPath *bezPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[bezPath moveToPoint:fixedPointStart];
[bezPath addLineToPoint:draggedPointEnd];
[bezPath stroke];
```

Then call `[self setNeedsDisplay]` in `-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` in your UIView to pass the new coordinates of the point that was dragged and have it redrawn.

But as I mentioned, I need the line to specifically be a fixed length.

One other thing (not sure if it would make a difference), the line is actually part of a larger `UIBezierPath` of an irregular shape. The "specific fixed point" shown in the picture is the point of attachement of this line to the larger irregular `UIBezierPath`. The line is drawn as part of the same `UIBezierPath` as you will see in the following code.

So here is what I have now:

```
//    I AM CREATING THE FIXED POINT HERE THAT IS BEING RETURNED BY A CUSTOM METHOD 
WHICH FINDS THE POINT OF ATTACHEMENT TO THE LARGER IRREGULAR SHAPED UIBEZIERPATH.
//    THE DRAGGABLE POINTS ARE ACTUALLY UIVIEW'S AND I'M USING THEIR ORIGINS.

CGPoint fixedPoint = [aPath findCurveBezierPathPointInBetweenTheStartPoint:point1.frame.origin
                                                             theEndPoint:topCurvePoint.frame.origin 
                                       withFirstControlPoint:topCurveFirstControlPoint.frame.origin
                   andSecondControlPoint:topCurveSecondControlPoint.frame.origin atPercentage:0.3];




//    This is the fixed point
CGPoint startPoint = fixedPoint;

//    This is the point that is going to be able to be dragged
CGPoint endPoint = topCurveFirstControlPoint.frame.origin;


//    I am finding the angle in between these two points to pass in an CGAffineTransform for the rotation. 
float angle = [self getRotatingAngle:startPoint secondPoint:endPoint];
NSLog(@"Angle in Radians: %f",angle);



//    I am creating the transform by passing in the angle and doing the necessary translations for the rotation to occur on the fixed point. 
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(fixedPoint.x, fixedPoint.y);
transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, angle);
transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform,-fixedPoint.x,-fixedPoint.y);


//  I am setting up to draw the line of fixed length and applying the transform and 
[aPath moveToPoint:startPoint];
[aPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(fixedPoint.x, fixedPoint.y - 60)];
[aPath applyTransform:transform];



// I then continue to draw the rest of the BezierPath and stroke it at the end.    
[aPath moveToPoint:point1.frame.origin];

[aPath addCurveToPoint:topCurvePoint.frame.origin controlPoint1:topCurveFirstControlPoint.frame.origin controlPoint2:topCurveSecondControlPoint.frame.origin];
```

So my question is:
How do I find the **correct angle** to have the fixed line be transformed by every time `drawRect:`is called when the draggable point finds a new position?

The method I use to find the angle between the fixed point and dragged point gives me the correct angle as I have tested it. However, I can't figure out how to apply the angle between those two points in a way that would rotate the line correctly in respect to the draggable point.

EDIT: Added [Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKmsC.jpg) for a better explanation of what I'm trying to accomplish exactly.

Comment: Pythagoras is your friend.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? I know the angle between the two points, I am having a hard time applying it for the rotation.

Answer (score 0):

Why you are transforming it? Its simple geometry. You can find the angle between centre and your current point. Since length is equal so your path is basically a circle. So find the point on circle using centre point and the angle.
Suppose the after dragging your touch point is currentPoint.
To find angle use:

```
CGFloat angle = atan2f(currentPoint.y - centre.y, currentPoint.x - centre.x);
```

Now find the point on circle which corresponds to the above angle:

```
finalPoint.x = centre.x + length * cosf(angle);
finalPoint.y = centre.y + length * sinf(angle);
```

where length is your fixed length. Now you can just draw a line between centre and finalPoint using quartz-2d.

Note: Sometimes angle can become negative. So may be in your implementation you want to convert it to equivalent +ve angle.

```
if (angle < 0)
     angle += 2 * M_PI;
```